# Can I rely on DataAvailable for an SSL-wrapped networkstream?

Tags: c#, ssl, network-programming

I'm dealing with an application that does a lot of asynchronous reading. To improve performance, I'd like to directly do a synchronous call to `Read` from an `SslStream` provided that the call does not block.

The `SslStream` itself does not provide a `DataAvailable` property like the underlying `NetworkStream` does.

So, given that I know that it's a wrapped network stream being read, will the `true` in `DataAvailable` guarantee that the call to the `SslStream` won't cause a block?

Like this:

```
public void Read(NetworkStream netStream, SslStream sslStream)
{
    // given that netStream is the inner stream of sslStream
    if (netStream.DataAvailable)
    {
        // Will not block
        sslStream.Read(...);
    }
    else
    {
        // Would block
        sslStream.Read(...);
    }
}
```

The `SslStream` is already authenticated and ready to go. I'm not sure if there are any additional overhead apart from the encrypting/decrypting. I assume the answer is reliant on if the `SslStream` requires a read of more than one byte from the underlying stream in order to read one encrypted byte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it doesn't guarantee that, because there are SSL Records at the next layer down, and you may not have received an entire one yet, and cryptologically speaking you can't do anything until you have it all, as you first have to check the MAc for integrity purposes.

But more to the point, I question the whole strategy. Just issue the reads as you need them in normal code: don't try to guess which mode will work best in each situation. The SSL overhead will probably swamp the sync/async difference, and the network bandwidth limitation will swamp them both.

Comment: Thank you. I will just go with asyncronous reading throughout, unless I know the stream to be a normal networkstream without SSL.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the cipher in use- endpoints using RC4 or another stream cipher are more likely to be decryptable one byte at a time, but no guarantees. An endpoint configured for DES or other block ciphers will wait until a full block is available.

You could do some screwy stuff with a peekable intermediate buffering stream and try to make sure you've got a reasonable block size before making a blocking read, but that's nasty.

If you absolutely can't block, I'd stick to BeginRead and a completion delegate.

Comment: Not really sure what cipher is being used. I'm not sure I can check the amount of available data in the stream either, only if the next call will block or not. It just would be really nice to avoid the additional overhead.

Comment: You need the entire SSL record before you can do anything, as you first have to check the MAC. It would be incorrect to deliver any bytes before checking the MAC, and incorrect to indicate that they are available ditto.